# Hover not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, hover

I'm trying to make a website compatibile to >IE8 (including IE). It turns out that hover effect is not working in any of IE versions. Here's my website [CLICK](http://jimmyweb.pl/projekty/dentmedica/)

When you navigate to page "Plan" there's a map of a flat. When you hover on one of two rooms it displays blue boxes on it (in every browser but not in IE). What is the problem?

This is HTML I'm using:

```
<div id="slide3" class="slide">
    <h1>Wybierz swój lokal</h1>
    <div class="floor-nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#floor0" class="floor-active">0</a></li>
            <li><a href="#floor1" class="floor-inactive">+1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="floor-0" class="floor">
        <img src="img/floor-0.png" />
        <a href="#" target="_blank" id="flat-1" class="flat">
            <span class="flat-desc">Lokal <span class="bold">45m²</span></span>
        </a>
        <a href="#" target="_blank" id="flat-2" class="flat">
            <span class="flat-desc">Lokal <span class="bold">25m²</span></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And some css:

```
.flat{
    background:none;
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:30px;
    text-decoration:none;
    z-index:900;
}

.flat .flat-desc{
    display:none;
    padding-left:38px;
    background:url(../img/plus-sign-white.png) left top no-repeat;
    line-height:20px;
}

.flat:hover{
    background:url(../img/flat-hover-bg.png);
}

.flat:hover .flat-desc{
    display:inline;
}
```

Do you have any ideas why is this happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I couldn't be able to find the issue for this. But I found a fix that works with me. Try

```
.flat{
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:30px;
    text-decoration:none;
    z-index:900;
    background-image: url( add url to a transparent pixel.png or a transparent pixel.gif );
}
```

Working [LIVE PREVIEW](http://madhushankarathnayake.com/temp/jimmyweb.pl/projekty/dentmedica/)

New code:

```
.flat{
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:30px;
    text-decoration:none;
    z-index:900;
    background-image: url(../img/flat-bg.png);
}
```

Comment: I thought it could be this but after that I assumed that this is stupid... but it turns out that it's not! ech, IE ;] thank you anyway, you helped me much!

Comment: +1 Had the same question, came to the same conclusion...ugh. At least it works! :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16367077/internet-explorer-hover-behavior-not-working