# Internet Explorer hover behavior not working

Tags: internet-explorer, css

I am having issue with IE9. When hovering .photo-nav the .photo-nav-icon should become visible. This works fine in every other browser I have tried.

Here is my mark-up:

```
<div class="photo-content">
    <img class="photo-img" src="/Images/empty.gif" />
    <div class="photo-nav prev" data-direction="prev">
        <div class="photo-nav-icon prev"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="photo-nav next" data-direction="next">
        <div class="photo-nav-icon next"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
.photo-content { position: relative; width: 600px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto; }
.photo-img { width: 600px; height: 400px; display:block; }
.photo-nav { position: absolute; height: 400px; width: 72px; }
.photo-nav.prev { top: 0; left: 0; }
.photo-nav.next { top: 0; right: 0; }
.photo-nav-icon { height: 60px; width: 60px; display: none; }
.photo-nav-icon.prev { margin: 170px 0 0 10px; }
.photo-nav-icon.next { background-position: 0 -60px; margin: 170px 10px 0 0; }
.photo-nav:hover > .photo-nav-icon { display: block; }
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iGanja/3GeEY/) of the problem.

Please note; the borders in the Fiddle are NOT part of the design. They are only there to show the framework since the images are not available. However, one interesting note is that IE does recognize the border of the photo-nav div and will then react to the hover, but not the body of the div.

One other note: If I change the img to a div and use the background-image instead, IE seems to work correctly, however this causes other issues, as I unable/unaware how to hook the onload event of a background image.

Lastly, the doctype is `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "click" since this is a hover problem, but as I said, the border is not part of my actual design, but hovering over it in the Fiddle does cause the proper effect.

I did consider that the absolute positioning was an issue, but as I stated, if I change the img to a div, it works fine.

Comment: I meant `:hover` .. as in hover over the left border of `.photo-nav` and you'll see `.photo-nav-icon` appear, its clear that its width collapsed for some reason making it seem like it isn't working

Comment: Yes, the border does work, but unfortunately, the border is not part of my actual final design. I'm not sure why it would collapse since I gave the .photo-nav a width, and the .photo-nav-icon also has a width.

Comment: Same that is kinda strange, I'm still trying to figure out *why* ..

Comment: Been pulling my hair out for hours!

Comment: Thanks @Spudley good call on that tag.

Comment: Found out something that hopefully helps - if you add background-color:white; to the photo-nav it all of a sudden works as it should.  Also tried adding text to the photo-nav and it works when you hover over the text.  Maybe has something to do with it not recognizing the height without something in it?

Comment: @Becuzz, yes I added a background color too and it worked. Problem is of course I cannot have a background color since I want the .photo-nav div to be transparent to the main image.  Another curious thing I noticed: I have a fadeOut/fadeIn jQuery effect when the image changes, and while the image is faded out, I can hover over the .photo-nav-icon itself and get it to appear. Okay, so that makes me think it's a z-index problem, but no, I can set z-index all day long with no affect.

Comment: The problem is that the img is intercepting the hover. You can see this by adding a background colour to .photo-nav:hover. It will never show that hover state, except in some seemingly random occasions. If that hover works, the red outlined element also shows. It also shows fine if you disable the display: none, showing that everything is in the correct place and not collapsing or anything. It looks like a bug, as even reducing the z-index of the img and increasing it on the sibling div doesn't work as expected. Not found a way to fix yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been unable to find anything further about this problem other than others have experienced the same thing. [Hover not working in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12666035/hover-not-working-in-internet-explorer/12666798#comment23469419_12666798)

As Woody suggested, this problem can be overcome by adding some background color, but of course, even with minimal opacity, this is not the UI we want as the navigation must be transparent.

One fix I did stumble across was to set the opacity property of the .photo-nav-icon rather than the display property:

```
.photo-nav-icon { background-image: url(/Images/nav.png); height: 60px; width: 60px; opacity:0; }
.photo-nav:hover > .photo-nav-icon { opacity:1; }
```

This only works for the icon itself and still doesn't respond to a hover over the entire .photo-nav div, and I don't like using opacity that much as every browser has its own way of handling it.

So, as is stated in the other SO post, I simply added a transparent gif image as the background of the .photo-nav div and that solved the problem:

```
.photo-nav { position: absolute; height: 400px; width: 72px; background:url(/Images/empty.gif); }
```

I am not thrilled with this solution, but it does work.

Comment: it does feel like an ie bug since the others all handle your code as expected. although it is annoying I would just add an explanatory comment to the CSS describing the defective behaviour.  assuming you don't need ie8 support you could go for an rgba(0,0,0,0) background although that is also a hack

Answer (score 1):

It works if you give .photo-nav a background (e.g. rgba(0,0,0,0.25), however I have no idea why.  I figured maybe it was a z-index problem, but giving the .photo-nav a z-index > 0 doesn't help here.

IE is only detecting mouse over the border as otherwise it seems to think the mouse is not over the photo-nav - same deal with JS mouse listener functions.

So things that make it work are :

a) Give the .photo-nav elements a background.
b) Remove position:relative from .photo-content

Comment: A background; yes that is the only thing I have found that works. I will post my answer soon, but I was hoping someone would come up with something more elegant and offer a reason why IE is behaving like this. Removing the relative position does cause the .photo-nav-icon divs to display, but they cannot be positioned properly otherwise.  Thanks for your ideas!